# Android backend with portrait orientation

Tags: android, playn

I try to change orientation for android backend but it doesn't change
at all..
I am trying with adding :screenOrientation="portrait" to my
manifest.xml but with no resoult...

Any suggestion how to change my orientation to portrait? Becouse in
default it is landscape...

Michael Bayne helped me on google goups with:

> You want to add the following to android/src/.../YourGameActivity.java:

```
@Override public boolean usePortraitOrientation () {
    return true;
}
```

Thanks Michael

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it in your manifest like this

android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: I try with manifest but it didn't work for me... maybe becouse of playn library.... but after adding ovveride function like Michael said for me it works well..

Comment: You need to change your manifest *and* override the method in `YourGameActivity.java`.